# Posible to set max depth of tree entity in TypeOrm?

Tags: node.js, database, typeorm

I want to use `TreeEntity` for my project. I want a tree of comment. But it depend on user. So I want limit depth of tree entity to avoid bug or something.

Is that posible?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this GitBook about tree entities : https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/tree-entities#working-with-tree-entities

You have `countAncestors` method that allow you to get the number of generation of an entity. This is useful for creation check. To list a certain number of generations, you can use the `depth` option in the finders methods.